# CSS: How to make consecutive lines in Paragraph Go over Left Floated Image with height

Tags: css, image, css-float

I have an image that is floated Left Next to the image there is text wrapped around the image.

I want to put the first line of text next to the image and the consecutive lines of text to go over the image. Is that possible?

Check out these images to see what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: problem]

The red square is the image.

```
<img class="someImage" ... />
<span class="someText" ... />

.someImage { float:left; }
.someText { line-height:1.5em; margin-top:10px; padding:0 22px; }
```

The image has a height. I want to wrap the lines of text (after the first line of the paragraph) on top of the image. I only want the first line to wrap around the image.

Comment: You could overlay the paragraph from the start and then do something like `span:first-line { padding-left: 20px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a workaround with `text-indent` and a background image. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/mFQEC/)**.

HTML

```
<div id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#text {
    background:url(your-image.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    text-indent:100px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you Giona and thanks to everyone who posted an answer, they were all helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into it, I think text-indent is exactly what you are looking for. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp

Answer (score 1):

if you are using float for positioning, it is difficult to achieve this as float does not break the regular flow of positioning. Use absolute positioning instead and z-index property to overlay. Then indent the first-line with left-margin, or text-indent property.

You can do it more easily if you put the image in background.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain more control of the first line using the ... wait for it ... `first-line` [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp)

`p:first-line {padding-left:50px;}`